# I can't do git push or pull because i get "The requested URL returned error: 403"

Tags: git, github, git-push

When I try to `git push origin master` and authenticate my credentials I get this error...

```
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: not possible to access 'https://github.com/ElmisteriOkay/joyeria-alejandros.git/':The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I found some solutions on stackoverflow in English that said that I had to add a configuration to the `[credential]` of the global .gitconfig file, I already did it and the same error continues.

I did the same procedure in the config file of the local repository and it didn't work for me either.

What else can I try to fix it? :(

Comment: is the repository created by yourself?

Comment: You can't write to this repository becuause you didn't been granted write permition. Please concat the repository owner and grant write permition to you.

Comment: yes it's mine @LeiYang

Comment: but the repository is mine. The only thing is that it's private but  i'm the owner.

Comment: First, remove or comment out `credential.helper` in gitconfig and try `git push origin master`. It's expected to ask you for the username and password (or token).

Comment: *You* think the repository is yours. Maybe it should *be* yours. But the server—the machine to which you're sending the `git push` requests—doesn't think the repository is yours, or at least, that you don't have write permission (some servers will let you take away your own write permission, in which case to fix it you just have to give yourself write permission again).

Answer (score 0):

> In short: it all depends on whose repository it is.

1. If you are the owner and push yourself, it depends on the project and everything else.

1.1. If you are the owner and someone else is pushing, then close the direct push to the master and give this right only to a select few.

2. If the repository is not yours and you need to fix the code in it, then work in your branch, push it and create a PR (Pull Request).

2.1. If the rep is not yours and you need to push something to the master, then request access from the owner of the rep.

Each item - taking into account the fact that access, in principle, can only be for reading the entire turnip or specific branches. By branches, you can configure the policy of their changes. For example, update only to maintainers and only through the PR.

And, in general, pushing to the master is *mauvais ton*.

In your case, most likely, it is the first one, since in the second case the error text would be completely different.

3. If we are talking about github, then only the owner of the turnip can do this. This also applies to other sites. On self-hosted repositories, there could potentially be options through top privileges everywhere for everything.
4. As a workaround within the github - create a fork or clone the entire project into your account. Then work with fresh rap, with all the consequences